# nodejs mongodb and android studio slow fetch speed

Tags: java, android, node.js, mongodb

I have a system which, pulls data from my server and stores it to a mobile SQL database via android studio. It works but it is painful slow like 30mins. I have around 86000 records in my database and want to pull all of them out of the server. What is the best way to do this?

Presently I get the count from the server and then query the server database until i find each ID and then send that result back to my mobile app.

```java
app.post("/get_data", function(req, res)
{
    var Id_request = req.body.Id_request;//The requested ID

    var query = {Val_String : Id_request};//Query value
    //console.log(query);
    //Data.find({}, function(err, result) {//Finds all data
    Data.findOne(query, function(err, result) {//Finds all data
    if (err) {
      //res.status(400).send(err);
      console.log("Sending error");
      res.status(200).send();
    } else {
      return res.json(result);
    }
  });
});
```

I use a recersive function in my pull request for each ID

```
private void call_method()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Id_request", Integer.toString(data_pointer));//The ID value
        Call<Fetch_result> call = retrofitInterface.executeGet_data(map);//Run the post
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Fetch_result>() {
            //call.enqueue(new Callback<Fetch_result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Fetch_result> call, Response<Fetch_result> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200)//Successful login
                {
                    D1= response.body().getT1_String();
                    D2= response.body().getT2_String();
                  
                    data_pointer = data_pointer + 1;
                    boolean result = BLE_DB.addData_Downloaded(D1,D2);//Add data
    
                    if(data_pointer<= Total_entries) {//Call method again
                        call_method();//Recursive here
                    }else if (data_pointer > Total_entries){
                        Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(),"All data received");
                    }

                } else if (response.code() == 404) {
                    Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Get data fail");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Fetch_result> call, Throwable t) {
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Get data error");
            }
        });
    }
```

**How Can I speed this up or do it differently to speed it up?**

Comment: Is it a must that you fetch ALL the data? Isn't there a way to fetch data on demand ?

Comment: Yeah I want to fetch the lot unfortunately. As it is essential a log of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to fetch as much data as possible at once ( limit the amount of queries you do ). It is hard to tell you how since I don't know your monogDB collection.
2. Try to do this with as little requests as possible. If you can return all the fetched data at once, this will save you some time.
3. JSON may be very slow when doing it on 86000 documents
4. Consider caching the data for future users

Right now i suspect what is limiting you is the fact that you are doing 86000 queries to the db... If you can get the entire mongoDB collection it may be a bit faster( look at notes )

Notes:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find ( omit the query parameter will result in fetching the entire collection )

Comment: So have a query with more results in it and send back more in one go. Thus limiting the query calls?

Comment: Also is it possible to send back X number of documents within the collection?

Comment: If you do db.collection.find()  without any query  then you will get all of the documents in the collection

Comment: Also is it possible to send back X number of documents within the collection? -> I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If I dont add the query you are correct I get all the entries. But I dont know how to receive all of them at once. So I was wondering if I could send like 5 then 5 thus the X

Comment: You could... but you have to implement some form of pagination. As to how to receive all of them... the same way you do just one. The same logic should apply when you put it in some form of loop ( sorry not a java developer here, but some form of looping the array and running the same code you do currently  ). But as  much as you can limit those requests it will be a good idea

Comment: What would be the code to limit the data? as ```Data.find({}).limit(5,function(err, result) {//Finds all data``` does not return any results

Comment: When you do Data.find() it returns a cursor to the data. Check this out:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#read-operations-cursors

Comment: Hey when you implement the changes I wonder how much this has improved the speed? Personal inquiry